# Using Association Class or just Association arrow

Tags: java, c#, oop, uml, object-oriented-analysis

I am currently studying OOP and UML together, there is confusion regarding the use of **association class** or just the **plain association**. Let say a **Company** hires **Person**, as far as I know there are two ways to associate them, the first way is just a regular type of association(I think this is aggregation) like this.
[Regular association](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB6So.jpg)[image]

The second way is to use an associative class, kind of like the one the ER diagram, but the **Company** class no longer has the responsibility to hire any **Person**.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Which one is correct? (It seems like the second one makes more sense, but the first one isn't wrong either)
2. If the first way is not wrong, but then wouldn't **Company** knows too much about **Person**?
3. In what situations do I consider using **association class** over regular **association**?

Comment: Just  a hint: your (Mickeysoft?) tool uses an articficial arrow head. UML uses an open arrow (thin lines) for directed associations. This is a blend with an extends relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your association is not an aggregation, an aggregation has an empty diamond (`<>`), so it is a simple association.

None of the association ends has a name even when navigable, so why are you using an association rather than may be a dependency if you do not want property ? Of course if it is not an association you cannot have an association-class.

In the class *Company* we can see the attribute *Employees*, are you sure you do not want :

[image]

or

[image]

You named the association as the operation (*hire*), of course you can but an association just represent a semantic relationship, so *hire* does not represent the operation.

As rightly said by @[Axel Scheithauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9430250/axel-scheithauer) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66964803/2458991) in case of an association-class the name of the class and the name of the association are common properties and must not be duplicated so cannot be different, from [formal/2017-12-05](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1) § *11.5.3.2 Association Classes* page 200 :

> Both Association and Class are Classifiers and hence have a set of common properties, like being able to have Features,
> having a name, etc. These properties are multiply inherited from the same construct (Classifier), and are not duplicated.
> Therefore, an AssociationClass has only one name, and has the set of Features that are defined for Classes and
> Associations.

About to use an association or an association-class it is a choice.

If you want to know the date the company hired an employee and the employee salary (when hired / current) for sure an association-class is a good choice clearly showing what you want.

But you can also have *Onboarding* as a third class out of an association class and having association between the 3 classes :

[image]

and you can also have date and salary as attributes of *Person* supposing a person is necessary an employee :

[image]

else you can have the class *Employee* inheriting *Person* and having these additional attributes :

[image]

You have Java and C# as tag, none of these language support association-class, so even you use an association-class in UML when implementing it in Java / C# you will probably use one of the two other solutions.

---

Because there is no bidirectional navigability a company knows his employees but an employee does not know the company or companies where he/her works, do you really want that ?

Comment: Amazing explanation! I always have a doubt when it comes to using bidirectional association/navigability, doesn't it imply circular dependency in code? Or, I can use bidirectional association in uml, then when I implement them in code, I do something else to avoid circular dependency?

Comment: @kjunz for sure a bidirectional association is more complicated to manage than a directional association, so do not use them for nothing in code, but when it is needed and alternative choices are more complicated/unclear better use bidirectional association. I encourage you to have the same in UML and implementation, else the UML model does not document/represent your code, so why to have it ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with everything that bruno said in his answer. However, I would add a third possibility: a simple *Class*.

If the relationship between two classes has *properties*, you have two options: An *association class* or a simple *class* associated with the two classes. The only advantage of taking an association class is, that you then can specify, that each pair of instances of the two associated classes can only be linked once. That means, each person can only work once for the same company. This is not quite realistic. In order to allow multiple links, you would need to specify `{non unique}` for the association ends of the association class (`{unique}` is the default). So, only in the `{unique}` case an association class adds semantics. If that's not needed I would avoid it.

One additional note: The association class is one element, but it is shown twice in a diagram, once as a rectangle and a second time as a line. Since they denote the same element, the name must be the same.

Comment: rightly view about the common name of the class and association (I edited my answer), that deserves an UV ;-)